# Read from a file that is continuously being updated

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I am writing some C code to process some data in a file, but I just learned that the file is going to be constantly added to (about 1 time/second, maybe faster).  So I'm wondering how do I keep reading from the file as its being added to.  Then when I get to the end, wait until the next line is added and then process it.  Then wait again and then process, and so on and so on.  I have something like:

```
while(1){
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
    while(line == NULL){
       //wait ?  then try to read again?
    }
    //tokenize line and do my stuff here
}
```

I thought I could maybe use inotify, but I am getting nowhere with that.  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: The whole line may not have gotten written so you may have to keep reading until you find `\n`. I would just wait a set period and try to read again unless you need something more advanced.

Comment: It might be better to set up a proper shared memory situation with the participating processes which allows proper synchronisation. You can even have the actual file memory-mapped into each process.

Comment: So, first the file contains like 46k lines that I need to process right away, then the file will be getting updated at around 1 line/sec.  So I do my while loop and then eventually I get to a point when fgets just gets a blank line.  So if I wait there, and then go manually put a new line in the file and save it how does fgets read that newly inputed line?  I guess I'm more than a little confused.

Comment: Your inner loop should not be testing `line` for nullity.  It should be more like: `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != 0) { process(line); } ...nanosleep?...; clearerr(file);` (which will then cycle around the `while (1)` loop for the next attempted read.

Comment: Jonathan - this makes sense.  Thank you. I'm just questioning then when I cycle back to the while(1) loop, I have to have closed the file?  And then reopen and fseek to the previously left off spot?  Is that right?

Comment: Oh, my idea worked.  I just don't know if its bad practice or not.  Thats something I really struggle with.  I'm doing an internship right now but I'm working with EE guys who don't code so I can't bounce ideas off anybody or ask questions.  Well I can ask but they just stare at me.  I feel like in class we aren't really learning these real world concepts.  I don't know.  I needs to get me a mentor already.

Comment: You could close and reopen the file and seek to where you were when you encountered EOF before, but the `clearerr(file);` I mentioned clears the EOF and error bits in the stream so that it will attempt to read more data from the file (without requiring you to close and reopen and reposition the current position in the file).

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way is using inotify, and the  direct way is  using the `read()` system call directly.

## using `inotify`

The following code may give you some help, It works well on Debian 7.0, GCC 4.7:

```
/*This is the sample program to notify us for the file creation and file deletion takes place in “/tmp/test_inotify” file*/
// Modified from: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define EVENT_BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

int main( )
{
  int length, i = 0;
  int fd;
  int wd;
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];

  /*creating the INOTIFY instance*/
  fd = inotify_init();
  /*checking for error*/
  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "inotify_init error" );
  }

  /* adding the “/tmp/test_inotify” test into watch list. Here, 
   * the suggestion is to validate the existence of the 
   * directory before adding into monitoring list.
   */
  wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "/tmp/test_inotify", IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_ACCESS | IN_MODIFY | IN_OPEN );

  /* read to determine the event change happens on “/tmp/test_inotify” file. 
   * Actually this read blocks until the change event occurs
   */ 
  length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 
  /* checking for error */
  if ( length < 0 ) {
    perror( "read" );
  }  

  /* actually read return the list of change events happens. 
   *  Here, read the change event one by one and process it accordingly.
   */
  while ( i < length ) {
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
    if( event->len == 0) {
      // For a single file watching, the event->name is empty, and event->len = 0
      printf(" Single file watching event happened\n");
    } else if ( event->len ) {
      if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "New directory %s created.\n", event->name );
        } else {
          printf( "New file %s created.\n", event->name );
        }
      } else if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "Directory %s deleted.\n", event->name );
        } else {
          printf( "File %s deleted.\n", event->name );
        }
      } else if( event->mask & IN_ACCESS ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "Directory %s accessed.\n", event->name );
        } else {
      printf(" File %s accessed. \n", event->name );
        }
      } else if( event->mask & IN_MODIFY ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "Directory %s modified.\n", event->name );
        } else {
      printf(" File %s modified. \n", event->name );
        }
      } else if( event->mask & IN_OPEN ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "Directory %s opened.\n", event->name );
        } else {
      printf(" File %s opened. \n", event->name );
        }
      } else {
    printf( "Directory or File is accessed by other mode\n");
      }
    }
    i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }

  /* removing the “/tmp/test_inotify” directory from the watch list. */
  inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );

  /* closing the INOTIFY instance */
  close( fd );

}
```

When runing the above program. You could test it by create a file or directoy named `/tmp/test_inotify`.

A detailed explanation could be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/)

## Use `read` system call

If a file is open, and have read to the end of current file size. the `read()` system call will return `0`. And if some writer wrote `N` bytes to this file later, and then the `read()` will just return `min(N, buffersize)`.

So it works correctly for your circumstance. Following is an examples of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef int FD ;

int main() {
  FD filed = open("/tmp/test_inotify", O_RDWR );
  char buf[128];

  if( !filed ) {
    printf("Openfile error\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  int nbytes;
  while(1) {
    nbytes = read(filed, buf, 16);
    printf("read %d bytes from file.\n", nbytes);
    if(nbytes > 0) {
      split_buffer_by_newline(buf); // split buffer by new line.
    }
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

## Reference

- Thanks to  Jonathan Leffler's Comment
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/

Comment: The trouble with `read()` on a plain file is that it returns 0 immediately when the read position is at the end of the file.  So, you have to do some sort of waiting before trying a new read.  This is in contrast to read on a pipe or socket or FIFO, which will block waiting for more data to arrive. The `inotify` information is probably the best way to deal with it.  That or loop and sleep...

Comment: You seem to have included an awful lot of content from the site you have linked. It's OK to include some, provided you give proper attribution (as you have here), but it's often not appropriate to make it so much of your answer. Please consider trying to add more of your own content to it? (I know you are editing it now, and perhaps seem to be doing just that.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I will try to post my own answer next time. Here is the explanation for this answers: 1. Although the code is copied from the reference, but the original code is not work, and I have modified and update about 20% of the code.  2. I am about to improve and add new content to this answers.

Comment: How this approach can be used for external command? for example need to monitor external command output that prints something after few seconds

Comment: Thanks for post @KunLing. I have tried posted example. I have changed to my local machine path. When I have created the new file only once getting log file is created after that it simply coming out. I am trying to verify continuously list of file creation in the directly .

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int
main()
{

    char            ch;
    FILE           *fp;
    long int        nbytes_read = 0;
    char            str       [128];
    int             j = 0;
    int             first_time = 1;
    memset(str, '\0', 128);
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while (1) {
            if (first_time != 1) {
                    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
                    fseek(fp, nbytes_read, SEEK_SET);
                    sleep(10);

            }
            if (fp != NULL) {
                    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
                            if (ch == '\n') {
                                    str[j++] = ch;
                                    printf("%s", str);
                                    memset(str, '\0', 128);
                                    j = 0;
                            } else {
                                    str[j++] = ch;
                            }
                            nbytes_read++;


                    }
                    //printf("%ld\n", nbytes_read);
                    first_time = 0;
            }
            fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html) with the `fileno(file)` as the file-descriptor. `select` will return either with a timeout (if you set a timeout) or when you can read from the file.

Comment: The definition of [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) in POSIX says: _File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions._

Answer (score -1):

Using `select` can be a good choice but if you do not wish to use it, you can add a sleep for a small amount of milliseconds before reading value.

Comment: The definition of [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) in POSIX says: _File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions._