# Reading data from a file being frequently updated in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a C code to read data from a file (and then process it) being constatly appended by some software in interval of 9 seconds
Here is a prototype of the actual code( i haven't pasted the original code here, it's of 250 lines ) -

```
while(1){
    while(ch ! = EOF){
        ch = fgetc(File pointer)
        //read from the file and do the required
    }
    clearerr(File pointer);
    sleep(9); //after every 9 seconds the new data is added to the file by some external software
    ch = fgetc(File pointer);
    printf("The value of ch is %d",ch);
}
```

But here the code reads the data from the data file once then when EOF occurs it breaks out of inner while loop and goes to the outer loop and gets stuck there only. I expected that clearerr(File pointer) will erase the EOF from the file so that i will be able to read newly updated data but instaed i'm getting stuck at that EOF and am unable to read new data. The print statement keeps on printing the EOF so it means it doesn't get erased from the file.
How can i fix this issue?

Since i did'nt had much knowledge about that other software, i tried updating the data myself, pasting and saving after 1 EOF is detected and my program is on sleep

Also when i ran my program in one terminal and `tail -f file_name.txt` in an other terminal parallely the program then everything works fine. I'm able to read the new data. Why is it so?

**Note -** I've already read this question( link given below ) and accordingly i've used clearerr(File pointer) but it's not deleting the current EOF so i'm unable to read the newly updated data from the file.

[Read from a file that is continuously being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725586/read-from-a-file-that-is-continuously-being-updated)

Here is the original code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"link.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<unistd.h>

char file_time[20],file_date[20],file_year[20],file_month[20],time_interval[20],mac_addr[40];
float store_voltage,store_pressure,store_temp1,store_temp2,store_humid,store_ntctherm,rssi_no,lqi_no; 
char input_filename[30],output_filename[30],corrected_year[20],ch;
int first_time =0,cursor_position=0,no_of_stack,timestamp_detected=0,file_has_ended=0;

stack *s;   

int input_func,flag=1,order=1,restart=0;

void output(){

    FILE *fi = fopen(output_filename,"a");             /*file is opened and closed after each input by the user because in the 
    output user only wants the data for last some of the readings for plotting the graph*/

        printf("How many stacks you want to print\n");  
        while(1){
            if(scanf("%d",&no_of_stack)!=1){                 //error handling
                printf("Please enter valid input\n");
                scanf("%c",&ch);
            }
            else
                break;
        }          
        /*like the program keep on recording the data as stacks and prints 
        whatever no of stacks i want it to print , also this asking od the no_of_stacks should take place till 
        the program runs*/  
        printList(&s,no_of_stack,fi); 

    printf("Please wait, Updating logs..............................................................\n");
    fclose(fi);
    // sleep(atoi(time_interval));                    //this sleep can be removed also, this is done so as to 
    // sleep(2);
    printf("Done \n");

}

void input(){

    int i=0,j,initial_lines=0;
    char ch=0;

    fflush(stdout);
    FILE *fp = fopen(input_filename,"r");               /*file is closed and opened in each iteration to handle buffer overflow
    because since the data in input file keeps on increasing so the input buffer will also increase so to tackle this the file is
    reopened again and again and the file pointer starts reading from the point where it left off instead of reading whole file 
    again and again*/  
    if(fp==NULL){

        printf("input_filename - %s",input_filename);
        printf("No file found of this name: %s\n",input_filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    ch=fgetc(fp);
    ch = fgetc(fp);

    if(first_time == 1){ 
    printf("file is openend first time\n");                    //this is to record whether it's the first time user's reading the file
        while(1){
            if(initial_lines == 3){           
                break;                        // This is just to skip some useless lines in input file 
            }
            if(ch=='\n'){
                initial_lines++;
            }
            ch = fgetc(fp);
        }
        initial_lines = 0;
        first_time =0;    
    } 


    fseek(fp, 10, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("Cursor set to  %d position after fseek\n",cursor_position);

    ch=fgetc(fp);
    if(ch==EOF){
    printf("here comes ch %d\n",ch);}

    char str[100];

    while(1){

    while(ch!=EOF){               //reading till end of file 

        input_func++; 
        timestamp_detected=0;                         
        restart=0;

        fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
        while(1){                                       //this is just string matching for taking input
            if(!strcmp(str,"Timestamp")){
                timestamp_detected=1;
                break;                  
            }
            if(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)==EOF){
                file_has_ended = 1;
                break;
            }
        }


        if(timestamp_detected){              //taking input 

            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",file_month);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",file_date);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",file_time);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",file_year);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);

            // printf("%s %s")

            for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                corrected_year[i] = file_year[i];
            }
            corrected_year[4] = '\0';


            fseek(fp,36,SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",mac_addr);
            // printf("mac addr - %s",mac_addr);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
            if(!strcmp(str,"RSSI")){
                fscanf(fp,"%f",&rssi_no);
            }
            else
                restart =1;

            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
            if(!strcmp(str,"LQI")){
                fscanf(fp,"%f",&lqi_no);
            }
            else
                restart =1;

            if(restart){
                continue;
            }

            order=1;
            while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)){
                if(!strcmp(str,"+[Node_Voltage]")){

                    fseek(fp,3,SEEK_CUR);                       
                    fscanf(fp,"%f",&store_voltage);
                    order=2;
                    break;
                }   
                else if(!strcmp(str,"Timestamp")){
                    fseek(fp,-20,SEEK_CUR);
                    restart =1;
                    break;
                }           
            }
            if(restart){
                continue;
            }

            fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
            printf("str value - %s\n",str);
            while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)){

                if( !strcmp(str,"+[P_MS5637]") && order==2 ){

                    fseek(fp,7,SEEK_CUR);
                    fscanf(fp,"%f",&store_pressure);
                    printf("pressure - %f stored, order - %d\n",store_pressure,order);
                    order++;
                }
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                if( !strcmp(str,"+[NTC_THERM") && order==3 ){

                    fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                    fscanf(fp,"%s",str);                        
                    fseek(fp,5,SEEK_CUR);
                    fscanf(fp,"%f",&store_ntctherm);
                    printf("ntc_therm - %f stored, order - %d\n",store_ntctherm,order);
                    order++;
                }
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                printf("after ntc%s\n",str);
                if( !strcmp(str,"+[Temp_LM75B]") && order==4 ){

                    fseek(fp,5,SEEK_CUR);                     
                    fscanf(fp,"%f",&store_temp1);
                    printf("temprature - %f stored, order - %d\n",store_temp1,order);
                    order++;
                }
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);

                if( !strcmp(str,"+[RH_CC2D33S]") && order==5 ){

                    fseek(fp,5,SEEK_CUR);
                    fscanf(fp,"%f",&store_humid);
                    printf("humid - %f stored, order - %d\n",store_humid,order);
                    order++;
                }
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                if( !strcmp(str,"+[Temp_CC2D33S]") && order==6){

                    fseek(fp,3,SEEK_CUR);
                    fscanf(fp,"%f",&store_temp2);
                    printf("temp2 - %f stored, order - %d\n",store_temp2,order);
                    order++;
                }
                if(order==7){
                    printf("items pushed\n\n\n");
                    push(&s,file_date,file_time,file_month,corrected_year,store_pressure,store_ntctherm,store_temp1,store_temp2,store_humid,store_voltage,rssi_no,lqi_no,mac_addr);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        if(ch==EOF)
            printf("the value of EOF is %d\n",ch);
        cursor_position = ftell(fp);          //recording the cursor position

    }
    printf("\n\n\nend of file detected\n");
            clearerr(fp);
            sleep(9);
        printf("i'm sleeping\n");
        fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
        printf("the value of str is after sleeping- %s\n",str);
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        printf("the value of ch is after sleeping- %d\n",ch);

}
    // fclose(fp);
}



    //shift the control of the program, printing takes place...........




int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int input_func = 0;


    // Enter the time interval in seconds
    if(argv[1]==NULL || argv[2]==NULL || argv[3]==NULL){
        printf("Invalid Format, Use the format specified below\n ./[executable] [Input File Name] [Output File Name] [Time Interval(in seconds)]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(time_interval,argv[3]);
    strcpy(output_filename,argv[2]);
    strcpy(input_filename,argv[1]);


    create(&s);                    //creating the stack

    first_time = 1;               

    while(1){
        input();               //runin the input function then 
        output();
    }

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: I don't see why the answer to the question you link don't solve your problem. Without a [mcve], I vote to close your question.

Comment: In the link i gave in the question, please see the comment by JonathanLeffler, that thing i implemented here but it's not working but on using tail -f filename.txt in some other terminal it works.

Comment: What's the type of `ch`?  Were it my code, the inner while would be `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { … }`, and that would be the only use of `fgetc()`.  As written, you throw away the first character read after the sleep.  It would be better to show compilable code; `File pointer` is not a valid identifier, of course.  An MCVE ([MCVE]) would be helpful.  The body of the inner loop could just do `putchar(ch)`, of course.

Comment: It's int ch . Ya I put that ch after the sleep statement to see whether it is still detecting the previous EOF and it was actually.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i've pasted the complete code, please have a look

Comment: Given the faulty inner loop logic, which also doesn't check the newly read character for EOF, you did need to set `ch` to some value other than EOF after the sleep.  The way you did it though was sub-optimal.

Comment: That is not an MCVE!   Please read about what an MCVE is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh you were right, the inner loop logic was faulty, setting ch to 0 after inner loop solves the problem.